# CryptographicException when trying to open a certificate from dotnetcore

Tags: .net, docker, authentication, .net-core, certificate

When running dotnet core in docker, i recently got this  cryptic  dotnet exception .

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Unix LocalMachine X509Store is limited to the Root and CertificateAuthority stores.|
> ---\u003e System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Unix LocalMachine X509Store is limited to the Root and CertificateAuthority stores.|

Below exception, I got when I tried to open a certificate from my docker certificate store

> x509Store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly)

The cause of the error was that the certificate was missing from my docker instance.

The exception thrown is not at all helpfull

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you're trying to open `new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine)`.  The exception tells you that it's not supported on Unix.

`new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser)` is the closest match.  Or, since it's Unix, don't bother with the stores...